# How would I hide an HTML element in a media query?

Tags: html, css, gridview, flexbox, media-queries

I'm currently working with three different media queries each of which has a different amount of content.

The Mobile site only had one column with text and an iframe video.
The Tablet media query has two columns with the same content.
The Desktop media query has three columns with the same content.

I'm hiding content on the Mobile site by hiding elements with display:none however all this does is get rid of the content. It still fills some space on the page making the other elements I want to keep behave badly with spacing.

What Can I do to make my other elements ignore the 'hidden' divs?

I have tried giving .column { width: 50% } in the Tablet media query but all it does is expand the 3rd (hidden) column div leaving lots of dead space.

In this picture you can see the problem as the hidden div is still taking some space to the right of the 2nd video causing all sorts of spacing issues:

[image: spacing]

The div on the desktop media query looks like this which is perfect:

[image]
HTML:

```
 <div class="chan-content">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-text">
        <h3 id="hide"> Bla bla bla</h3>
        <p id="hide" class="col-p-shift">
          Bla bla bla
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="vid-contain vid-anim">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/momqQl-9-tg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-text">
        <h3 id="hide">Bla bla bla</h3>
        <p id="hide" class="col-p-shift">
          Bla bla bla 
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="hide" class="vid-contain vid-anim">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xAngb0wRZJM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="column-text">
        <h3 id="hide-desktop"> Bla bla bla</h3>
        <p id="hide-desktop" class="col-p-shift">
          Bla bla bla
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="hide-desktop" class="vid-contain vid-anim">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrwxZcsKIJU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
body  {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.container  { /* Mobile */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "advert"
    "main"
    "footer";
  text-align: center;
}

header  {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

main  {
  grid-area: main;
}

advert  {
  grid-area: advert;
  background: url(./mi-vr-5.jpg);
}

footer  {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.title  {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.title-shift  {
  margin: 90px 0 0 0;
}

.title-shift-h3  {
  transform: translate(0, -25px)
}

.title-shift-p  {
  transform: translate(0, 15px)
}

.text-style  {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(80deg, white, #AEC6DF);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.channel  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.chan-img  {
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.chan-img:hover  {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 1s;
}

.chan-content {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56%;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

iframe  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.line  {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

a  {
  color: white;
}

img  {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.bot-bar  {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.bot-bar > a {
  color: white;
}

.bot-bar > a > img  {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.bot-bar > a > img:hover  {
  transition: 0.7s;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

#hide  {
  display: none;
}

#hide-desktop  {
  display: none;
}

form  {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.input-div  {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

input  {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

textarea  {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.bg-righttoleft {
  -webkit-animation: bg-righttoleft 3s ease-in-out;
  background-position: 50% 75%;
  background-size: 1000px;
}

.righttoleft  {
  animation-name: righttoleft;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.lefttoright  {
  animation-name: lefttoright;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.vid-anim  {
  animation-name: lefttoright;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes bg-righttoleft {
  0% {
    background-position: 20% 75%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50% 75%;
  }
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0%  {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%  {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes righttoleft {
  0%  {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%  {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes lefttoright {
  0%  {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%  {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@media only screen /* Tablet */
  and (min-width: 885px) {
    .container  {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
      grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "advert"
      "main"
      "footer";
    }

    body  {
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    header  {
      font-size: 1.4em;
    }

    advert  {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-size: 0.9em;
    }

    .title-shift-p  {
      transform: translate(0, -5px);
    }

    .channel  {
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
    }

    .chan-text  {
      transform: translate(0, 18px);
      margin: 0 20px 0 40px;
    }

    .chan-content  {
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      flex: 0 1 auto;
      padding-bottom: 0%;
      background: green;
    }

    .column  {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 0 10px 0;
      background: yellow;
    }

    .vid-contain  {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-bottom: 56%;
    }

    .column-text  {
      min-height: 320px;
    }

    iframe  {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }

    .bot-bar  {
      font-size: 0.8em;
      margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    img  {
      margin: 10px 0 0 0;
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 50%;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .vid-anim  {
      animation-name: opacity;
      animation-duration: 6s;
    }

    .bg-righttoleft {
      background-size: 2000px;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    @keyframes bg-righttoleft {
      0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 50% 50%;
      }
    }

    #hide  {
      display: block;
    }

    #hide-desktop  {
      display: none;
    }
  }

@media screen /* Desktop/Laptop */
  and (min-width: 1900px) {
    .container  {
      max-width: 2500px;
      grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
      grid-template-areas:
      "header header"
      "sidebar advert"
      "sidebar main"
      "footer footer";
    }

    sidebar  {
      background: url(./history-vr-banner.jpg);
    }

    .bot-bar  {
      font-size: 0.8em;
    }

    .column  {
      width: 33.3%
    }

    .column-text  {
      min-height: 310px;
      padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    #hide-desktop  {
      display: block;
    }
  }
```

Comment: When asking such question, you should try to reproduce the problem with similar setting while getting rid of most unimportant stuff. A lot of the CSS and HTML can be stripped away for this problem. It is more difficult for someone to help you.

Comment: That should be better  so... Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem you are experiencing stems from the fact that your column is not hidden only the content inside of it.  To fix your issue without too much rewriting you have two options. option one add a nth-child selector to your column class and give it a display of none allowing you to show and hide it using your media queries or simply add a new class to the column you wish to hide and give that the display none property which you would then add to your media queries. Base your decision on how much browser compatibility you wish to uphold.

```
.column:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```
.column.hide-mobile {
    display: none;
}
```

The code in the snippet below has the nth-child solution in it just above your @keyframes. Hope this helps

```css
body {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  /* Mobile */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "advert" "main" "footer";
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px 0 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
}

advert {
  grid-area: advert;
  background: url(./mi-vr-5.jpg);
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.title {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.title-shift {
  margin: 90px 0 0 0;
}

.title-shift-h3 {
  transform: translate(0, -25px)
}

.title-shift-p {
  transform: translate(0, 15px)
}

.text-style {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(80deg, white, #AEC6DF);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.channel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.chan-img {
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.chan-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 1s;
}

.chan-content {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56%;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

img {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.bot-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.bot-bar>a {
  color: white;
}

.bot-bar>a>img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.bot-bar>a>img:hover {
  transition: 0.7s;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

#hide {
  display: none;
}

#hide-desktop {
  display: none;
}

form {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

.input-div {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

textarea {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.bg-righttoleft {
  -webkit-animation: bg-righttoleft 3s ease-in-out;
  background-position: 50% 75%;
  background-size: 1000px;
}

.righttoleft {
  animation-name: righttoleft;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.lefttoright {
  animation-name: lefttoright;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.vid-anim {
  animation-name: lefttoright;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

.column:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes bg-righttoleft {
  0% {
    background-position: 20% 75%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50% 75%;
  }
}

@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes righttoleft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes lefttoright {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@media only screen
/* Tablet */

and (min-width: 885px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "advert" "main" "footer";
  }
  body {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  header {
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  advert {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
  .title-shift-p {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
  .channel {
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  }
  .chan-text {
    transform: translate(0, 18px);
    margin: 0 20px 0 40px;
  }
  .chan-content {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    background: green;
  }
  .column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 10px 0;
    background: yellow;
  }
  .vid-contain {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 56%;
  }
  .column-text {
    min-height: 320px;
  }
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .bot-bar {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  }
  img {
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .vid-anim {
    animation-name: opacity;
    animation-duration: 6s;
  }
  .bg-righttoleft {
    background-size: 2000px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
  }
  @keyframes bg-righttoleft {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 50% 50%;
    }
  }
  #hide {
    display: block;
  }
  #hide-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  
}

@media screen
/* Desktop/Laptop */

and (min-width: 1900px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 2500px;
    grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 340px 1fr 50px;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "sidebar advert" "sidebar main" "footer footer";
  }
  sidebar {
    background: url(./history-vr-banner.jpg);
  }
  .bot-bar {
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  .column {
    width: 33.3%
  }
  .column-text {
    min-height: 310px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  }
  #hide-desktop {
    display: block;
  }
  .column:nth-child(3) {
      display: flex;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="chan-content">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-text">
      <h3 id="hide">A comprehensive view of the Oculus Go</h3>
      <p id="hide" class="col-p-shift">
        This review is an extensive and in-depth insight into the pros and cons of owning an Oculus Go over the alternatives. At a much lower price point than the Oculus Rift, the Go has a few drawbacks. <br><br>No Oled display, no headphones and no space
        positioning. However, the resolution on the go is higher than the Rift giving a clearer, cleaner image. Perfect for media consumption.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="vid-contain vid-anim">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/momqQl-9-tg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-text">
      <h3 id="hide">An in-detail talk about the Oculus Quest</h3>
      <p id="hide" class="col-p-shift">
        After an explanation of the latest hardware Oculus intend on releasing Adam Savage Tested have a chat with Product Manager Sean Liu about the hardware inside the up and coming Oculus Quest. <br><br>The Quest will receive a resolution upgrade to
        1440-1600 whilst keeping the Oled colours Rift owners love as well as making sensors redundant with sensors built into the headset. Oh, and it's cordless!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="hide" class="vid-contain vid-anim">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xAngb0wRZJM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="column-text">
      <h3 id="hide-desktop">Chronos is a unique third-person experience</h3>
      <p id="hide-desktop" class="col-p-shift">
        Created by Oculus, Chronos is another take on what can be achieved with VR technology. The game is a third-person, room-based RPG with stunning 3D visuals and well-designed combat mechanics.
        <br><br>The concept is also original. As your character dies throughout the game he advances in age shuffling his abilities from melee combat to magic. Chronos is a therapeutic gaming experience that should not be missed!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="hide-desktop" class="vid-contain vid-anim">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrwxZcsKIJU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! So to be clear I needed to target the container of the container instead of the container its self?

Comment: I'm having some issues with keeping the iframe height. By playing with .column:nth-child(3) { display: block; } I can get them to aline in various combinations. What's going on here?

Comment: My pleasure Maximillian, you should be targeting the <div class="column"> you wish to hide with either the nth-child selector or by give that div a new class like <div class="column mobile-hide> then place display: none or display: block in the appropriate place / media query that will hide the entire div not just the content. Let me know if you have anymore questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not look into your media queries that much, you may not want to use display block. You are using grid and flexbox so using display block will interfere with how grid and flexbox handle item alignment.  So you may need to use display flex to bring it back on desktop not display block.

Comment: Ah interesting. That may be my problem. So instead of display: block; I can simply use display: flex; instead which serves the same purpose but is also more agreeable with my flexbox container?

Comment: Yes, after looking over your CSS a bit more I noticed you were using display flex on you column class so if you were to bring a column back from display none it would need to be display flex.  I have edited the code snippet I supplied earlier and everything seems to be working fine.  Let me know if you have anymore issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186231/discussion-between-maximilian-and-kjek-code).